# Ruby sort_by not working and sometimes throwing ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I understand that a hash is not supposed to have any order and what I am trying to do is gather data from a number of different APIs and then sort the results. My hash looks like this

```
hash = \ 
{{:train_id=>["DALY", "1"]}=>
  {0=>
    [{:train_no=>0,
      :arrival_station=>"MONT",
      :destination_departure_time=>"8",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   1=>
    [{:train_no=>1,
      :arrival_station=>"MONT",
      :destination_departure_time=>"23",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   2=>
    [{:train_no=>2,
      :arrival_station=>"MONT",
      :destination_departure_time=>"37",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   3=>
    [{:train_no=>0,
      :arrival_station=>"POWL",
      :destination_departure_time=>"7",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   4=>
    [{:train_no=>1,
      :arrival_station=>"POWL",
      :destination_departure_time=>"21",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   5=>
    [{:train_no=>2,
      :arrival_station=>"POWL",
      :destination_departure_time=>"36",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   6=>
    [{:train_no=>0,
      :arrival_station=>"CIVC",
      :destination_departure_time=>"5",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   7=>
    [{:train_no=>1,
      :arrival_station=>"CIVC",
      :destination_departure_time=>"19",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   8=>
    [{:train_no=>2,
      :arrival_station=>"CIVC",
      :destination_departure_time=>"34",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   9=>
    [{:train_no=>0,
      :arrival_station=>"16TH",
      :destination_departure_time=>"17",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}],
   10=>
    [{:train_no=>1,
      :arrival_station=>"16TH",
      :destination_departure_time=>"32",
      :destination=>"Pittsburg/Bay Point"}]},

 {:train_id=>["DALY", "5"]}=>{}
}
```

I need to sort by :train_no and when I use

```
sorted = hash.sort_by{|k,v| v[:train_no] }
```

I sometimes get the error

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed
```

which is possibly because one of the values is null, and if it doesn't fail it just returns the same unsorted sorted results.

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong (other than using a hash to store something I want to sort)?

Comment: What is the value of `b`?

Comment: What I can immediately say is that your hash is unusually complex. That is already a sign that you are doing something wrong. It is also difficult to give you advice on what to do because of the complexity. Reconsider the structure of the data.

Comment: Hashes DO have order starting from Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: b is the hash above.

Yes, it's a complex hash because I am comparing trains heading in one direction with all the possible train each one can connect with that are  heading in the other direction. I've already thought about changing the hash but since I have everything else working bar the sort I thought I'd ask the experts here first

Comment: Your code runs fine on my system. I edited your code in your question to clarify what the hash is, and remove the "b" variable name -- please see if I got your intent correct.

Comment: Simon, did my answer help you? If so, could you do me a favor and upvote it and/or accept it? (Otherwise I'd prefer to delete it if it didn't help)